# ErrorProvider Not Clearing

Tags: vb.net

I have two text boxes `txtLastName` and `txtFirstName` and one `ErrorProvider` control in my form. If user did not enter values in both textboxes, then error icon will appear after the event. When user put a value in txtLastName and did not put any value in txtFirstName, then it is okay. However, the error icon is still showing.

[image]

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    AddTags()
    AddHandler txtLastName.Validating, AddressOf RequiredUnless
    AddHandler txtFirstName.Validating, AddressOf RequiredUnless
End Sub

Sub AddTags()
    txtLastName.Tag = txtFirstName
    txtFirstName.Tag = txtLastName
End Sub

Public Sub RequiredUnless(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctrl As BaseEdit = TryCast(sender, BaseEdit)
    Dim ctrl2 As BaseEdit = ctrl.Tag
    Dim ErrProvider As New ErrorProvider

    If ctrl.Text = "" And ctrl2.Text = "" Then
        ErrProvider.SetError(ctrl, "This field cannot be empty")
    Else
        ErrProvider.SetError(ctrl, "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be creating the `ErrorProvider` in that code.  You're not keeping any reference to it so how can you ever clear it?  Next time the event is raised you create a new one and "clear" that, but that does nothing to the previous one.  You should be adding one `ErrorProvider` in the designer and always referring to that one.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the clue. I got it already. Used the ErrorProvider that I put on my designer as the reference key.